# How to draw unordered cutting lines in autocad

Tags: line, autocad, autodesk, cad

[image]

how do i make these rough, weird disectioning lines in autocad?

I searched on internet but thanks to my english, i couldn't find it anywhere. Since autocad is for so many professions, this mechanical engineering related question is even harder to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `SKETCH`

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2021/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-EFF06F5D-E8B2-44D9-8CE6-D8C100A37AAA-htm.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GT_Mo9JqY-Y

Comment: Yup, that's what i was looking for. Also in addition, decreasing increment smooths the drawing lines... (saw it in the video given, wanted to bring it on stackoverflow)